# What's the lowest value of $\sqrt{1+\frac4x} - \sqrt{1-x}$ for $0 < x ≤ 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What's the lowest value of $\sqrt{1+\frac4x} - \sqrt{1-x}$ for $0 < x
>  ≤ 1$

Encountered this on 2018 Tubitak National Mathematics Olympiads and tried to solve it using Arithmetic and Geometric Mean Inequality but couldn't manage to get an answer, would be appreciated if anyone could solve using AGM (other solutions would be appreciated too if it's not too advanced).

Comment: What is too advanced? This may be solved using derivatives. Tell us what you have tried and what you think so we can adapt our answers to your needs.

Comment: There should be a way to solve it without derivatives cause students weren't told to use derivatives but you can still post it and I'd see if I can understand it.

Comment: Please give us your thoughts about the problem and edit your questions to show your work.

Comment: I've tried to use AGM as I said in the question but I couldn't came out with something, other than that I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Please do show us what you tried even if you did not succeed.

Comment: _How_ did you try to use AM-GM? How far did that take you?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi(x) = \sqrt{1+\frac4x} - \sqrt{1-x}$.

For $x \in (0,1]$, $\varphi(x) \ge \sqrt{1+\frac41} - 1 = \sqrt{5} - 1 > 0$. This means minimizing $\varphi(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $\varphi(x)^2$. Notice

$$\varphi(x)^2 = \left( 1 + \frac4x \right) + ( 1 - x )  - 2\sqrt{\left( 1 + \frac4x \right)(1-x)}
= 2 + \frac4x - x - 2\sqrt{\frac4x - x - 3}$$
If we set $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac4x - x - 3}$, we have

$$\varphi(x)^2 = 2 + (\psi(x)^2 + 3) - 2\psi(x) = 4 + (\psi(x)-1)^2 \ge 4\implies \varphi(x) \ge 2$$

In order for what's on the right to become an equality, we need
$$\psi(x) = 1 \iff \frac4x - x - 3 = 1^2 \iff x(x+4) = 4 \implies x = \pm\sqrt{8} - 2$$

Since $x_+ = \sqrt{8}-2 \approx 0.8284 \in (0,1]$, we have

$$\psi(x_+) = 1 
\quad\implies\quad 
\varphi(x_+) = 2 
\quad\implies\quad 
\min_{x \in (0,1]} \varphi(x) = \varphi(x_+) = 2$$

**Update**

For something more advanced, the inequality $\varphi(x) \ge 2$ can be proved using [Aczél's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Aczel%27s_Inequality).

> Given real numbers $a_0, b_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $a_0^2 > |\vec{a}|^2$, $b_0^2 > |\vec{b}|^2$, we have
>   $$(a_0b_0 - \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})^2 \ge (a_0^2 - |\vec{a}|^2)(b_0^2 - |\vec{b}|^2)$$
>   with equality if and only if $\displaystyle\;\frac{\vec{a}}{a_0} = \frac{\vec{b}}{b_0}$.

For the problem at hand, let $u = \sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x}}$ and $v = \sqrt{1 - x}$.
Notice for $x \in (0,1]$, we have 
$$u^2 - 1 = \frac{4}{x} > 0\quad\text{ and }\quad 1 - v^2 = 1 - (1-x) = x > 0$$
Using Aczél's inequality, we obtain
$$
\varphi(x) = u-v = u\cdot 1 - 1 \cdot v
\ge \sqrt{(u^2-1)(1-v^2)} = \sqrt{\frac4x \cdot x} = \sqrt{4} = 2
$$
with equality when $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{u} = \frac{v}{1} \iff uv = 1$. The rest of argument is same as above and I won't repeat them here.